# Pandas dataframe operations too slow on dataset with a lot of columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a similarity matrix (pandas Dataframe) and I want to go through each product and get the **most 5 similar products**, then put them in a final Dataframe called `itemAffinity` but as the similarity matrix has 31878 items(products)=> means 31878 columns and 31878 rows . Executing the below function, could not be finished (takes a lot of time).

```
def get_items_similarity_score(similarity_matrix):
    products_list = similarity_matrix.columns.values.tolist()
    #Create an empty data frame to store item affinity scores for items.
    itemAffinity= pd.DataFrame(columns=('item1', 'item2', 'score'))
    rowCount=0
    for item in products_list:
        #get top 5 similar products which are not item
        if isinstance(item,int):
            series_sim = similarity_matrix.loc[item].nlargest(6)
            #print series_sim
            df = pd.DataFrame({'product':series_sim.index, 'score':series_sim.values})
            df = df[df['product'] != item]
            for r in range(len(df)):
                itemAffinity.loc[rowCount] = [item,df.iloc[r]['product'],df.iloc[r]['score']]
                rowCount +=1
                itemAffinity.sort_values("score", ascending=False, inplace=True)
    return itemAffinity
```

the function that I used to generate the similarity matrix:

```
def calculate_similarity(data_items):
"""Calculate the column-wise cosine similarity for a sparse
matrix. Return a new dataframe matrix with similarities.
"""
data_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(data_items)
#pairwise similarities between all samples in data_sparse.transpose()
similarities = cosine_similarity(data_sparse.transpose())
sim = pd.DataFrame(data=similarities, index= data_items.columns, columns= data_items.columns)
return sim
```

is there a way to have the expected result but more effective performance?

Comment: Can you share the schema for `similarity_matrix` ? How does the head look like ?

Comment: I added `calculate_similarity` function which generated the similarity_matrix. `data_items.columns` is product IDs

Comment: can you share the `.head()` for `data_items`?

Comment: data_items contain as values  0.0 or 1.0. product Ids as columns, and unique user_ids as rows. (cannot copy the head) It means for each row, if the user has bought a product, you find 1.0 otherwise 0.0

Answer (score 1):

Let `df` be your similarity matrix (I assume the main diagonal has been already nullifed to avoid hight self-similarities). Find separately the largest column element and its row index and combine the two pieces into a new dataframe:

```
# Toy matrix
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0.1,0.2],
                   'b':[0.5,0.,0.7],
                   'c':[0.5,0.75,0]}, index=('a','b','c'))
best = pd.concat([df.idxmax(), df.max()], axis=1).reset_index()
best.columns = "prod1", "prod2", "sim"
#  prod1 prod2   sim
#0     a     c  0.20
#1     b     c  0.70
#2     c     b  0.75
```

Comment: The diagonals could be high numbers, you either need to set them to the lowest value or remove them from the logic.

Comment: @SahilPuri You are right but preparing the matrix a different problem. I assume that the diagonal has been taken care of.

Comment: I have another question about the similarity matrix, actually not only the diagonals contain self-similarities. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51658056/6837132. Otherwise, I need a different solution as this returns only the  one most similar product, while I need more (5 as in code).

Comment: In the question, you said you want one. Getting more than one is an entirely different (and harder) problem. Please update your question, and then someone may answer it.

Comment: A possible solution to the new question: Get the top similarities, set them to 0 in the original matrix, and repeat the process 4 more times.